# What are Stack Exchange 'ticks'?

Tags: discussion, source-code

On most pages on Stack Exchange sites, there is an [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) request made to a URL like this one:

```
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ticks?_=xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

And the response is usually an alphabetic string like;

```
DkLMTD
```

What is this all about and what do the 'ticks' do?

If you visit any of the Stack Exchange sites in Firefox with [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29) enabled, you can see this as well.

Comment: Just a guess, so this is only a comment, but perhaps that's a "heartbeat" - used to keep a session active and for showing things like when someone else adds an answer to the question you're viewing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ticks are used by the WMD editor, seemingly it is a pseudo random generated string. It is appended to your post via a hidden input when you load a questions page. Using the tick they can determine when you *really* loaded the page, and whether or not they need to serve you with a captcha. Don't use this knowledge for evil!

```
$.get("/questions/ticks", function (b) 
{
   $("#post-editor-hidden").append("<input type='hidden' name='bullet' value='" + b + "' />")
});
```

Sessions don't need to be kept active because they never expire, and new post activity is designated by a 'heartbeat', which is a request sent to `/posts/#ID/new-activity-heartbeat`, which returns JSON that specifies whether or not new posts have been made and if so how many.

Comment: The source code changed a bit, but the logic is the same. It's now: `$.get("/questions/ticks", function(h) { g.append("<input type='hidden' name='i1l' value='" + h + "' />"); });`